# Reverse an existing number

Tags: java, reverse

Could you explain me how this code works? I have tried it with any input and it always gives right result. I think that they key its the line `reversenum = reversenum * 10;`but i need some explanation on it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   int num=123456789;
   int reversenum =0;
   while( num != 0 ){
      reversenum = reversenum * 10;
      reversenum = reversenum + num%10;
      num = num/10;
   }
   System.out.println("Reverse of specified number is: "+reversenum);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with 123456789 (`num`) and 0 (`reversenum`). Then, you multiply `reversenum` by 10: it remains 0. `num % 10` is the remainder when `num` is divided by 10: this is 9, which becomes `reversenum`. `num` is then divided by 10, but integer division gets the floor of fractional results, so you will get 12345678 as `num` (NOT 12345678.9). In the second pass, 9 (`reversenum`) is multiplied by 10 to get 90, and the last digit of `num` is added: 8. `reversenum` becomes 98 and `num` becomes 1234567. This keeps going until `num` is 0 and `reversenum` is 987654321; the `while` loop's condition will then be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each pass through the while loop, the current last digit of `num` is removed and it becomes the last digit of `reversenum`.  So the last digit of `num` is removed and it becomes the first digit added to `reversenum` (and thus the first digit of `reversenum`).  Then it takes what was originally the next to last digit of `num` and it becomes the second digit added to `reversenum` (and thus the second digit of `reversenum`).  This continues until no digits are left to move.

Let's look at the first pass:

`reversenum` becomes 0*10, which is 0.  Then you add `num%10`, which is 9.  So `reversenum` becomes 9.

Meanwhile the integer division makes `num` become 12345678

Looking at the next pass:

`reversnum` becomes 9*10 which is 90, then add `num%10` which is 8, so `reversenum` becomes 98.

Meanwhile integer division makes `num` become 1234567.

---

**small warning**

What would you think the reverse of 90 is?  You should be aware of this case.

Comment: Input 90,900,9000 ect gives output 9 .. not 09,009,0009.  thanks for this observation!

Comment: any suggestions to improve the code, so to not outgo zeros?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424294/inputting-a-number-then-reversing-it?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what the code does is:

- Take off the units digit from the original number.
- Add that digit to the rightmost position of the reverse.
- Multiply the reverse by 10, so the digit shifts up one.
- Divide the original by 10, to move on to the next digit.
- This happens until there are no more digits left.

Answer (score 0):

Let your number be 12345. We extract the digits from the end. First we find the remainder when 12345 divided by 10. The remainder comes to be 5.Now we add this to our reversenum which is supposed to store the reverse number. Then we divide 12345 by 10 . As a integer divided by a integer gives a integer value . Therefore

num = 12345/10 = 1234

We multiply 
reversenum by 10 so that reversenum becomes 50 and again add the remainder to reversenum So 2nd time reversenum becomes 54.Then we extract the last digit of 1234 (num variable). As you can see this continues till the total number is reversed i.e, num=0 (there are no more digits to be extracted).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while statement it is multiplying the reversenum variable by ten, then adding the remainder of the num/10 to reversenum, and then finally it divides the num by ten. It is possible for this while statement to end because since each variable is an int, dividing num by ten will always produce the rounded up version of num/10 if num is not evenly divisible by 10.